# Oracle SQL Developer: can bind variables begin with upper case letter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-adf, bind-variables

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to test a query to be used in an ADF application's read only view object. ADF documentation recommends using an uppercase letter to begin the name of a bind variable. So... I've creatively named mine **:BindVariable**

Funky part is SQL Developer appears to dislike bind variables that begin with an upper case letter.

**This query works**

```
select * from tablename
where id like :bindVariable
```

**This one does not**

```
select * from tablename
where id like :BindVariable
```

Am I correct in understanding that bind variable names cannot begin with an upper case letter? Or is there something else amiss here?

**EDIT**

Is this just an Oracle SQL Developer thing? :BindVariable works just fine in JDeveloper's database navigator.

Thanks for reading! Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Oracle SQL Developer: can bind variables begin with upper case letter?

Yes.

There is no issue with **SQL Developer**. I have tested it on version `3.2.20.10`

Please see the screenshots:

**Query:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

No issues in **SQL*Plus** either:

```
SQL> variable BindVariable VARCHAR2(20)
SQL> EXEC :BindVariable := 'SMITH'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE ename LIKE :BindVariable;

     EMPNO
----------
      7369

SQL>
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a version difference. We use Oracle SQL Developer Version 2.1.1.64 and JDK6 by default. I'm downloading SQL Developer 4.1.0.19 now and will give it a test in the morning. Thank you very much for the time and input.

Comment: You're welcome. It might be a version specific issue. Please let me know if newer version fixes the issue.

Comment: Seems like a version issue. I opted to install 3.2.20.09 instead of 4.1.0.19 (didn't require JDK8) and the issue is resolved. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @IdusOrtus So, the issue is certainly version specific. Thanks for the feedback.